# Working with native javascript plugin in directive and unit test suite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, leaflet

I have a native javascript plugin that is wrapped in a directive and used  in angular way.

Few lines of directive,

```
export default function () {
'use strict';
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        map: '=',
        options: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div id="map" class="leaflet-map"></div>'
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        //This code of native js class that 
        //is injecting svg inside given template

        scope.map = new MP.Map(scope.options);       

    }
  };
}
```

HTML

```
<mp-map options="opt" map="mapOpt"></mp-map>
```

Expected HTML

```
<div id="map"><svg>.. nodes of map .. </svg></div>
```

**Firstly**, I am trying to access **mapOpt** (i.e. instance of Mp.Map or binding with naitve js class in directive's link method) on **init** but failing to get instance of **MP.Map** in angular controller. Then I tried with $timeout (without any async data),so it worked.

**Secondly**, I wrote a unit test for directive to make sure `<mp-map>` is replaced by directive's template. But for that it's throwing error "Map container not found" (i.e error that native code is throwing).

Seems, my first step of defining directive is wrong.

Seeking help from Angularians.

I would appreciate prompt help.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT** : Few lines of MP class (Custom class)

```
FP.Map = L.Class.extend({

  options: {
              container: 'map',
              .....
           },

  ....

  // Map options
  this.options.map = L.extend(this.options.map, options.map);
  this.map = L.map(this.container, this.options.map);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's throwing error "Map container not found" (i.e error that native code is throwing).

How does your MP.map instance know what element to use? With Leaflet you add the element you want to use as the first parameter, the options object as the second: `new L.Map(element[0], scope.options);` I see you doing: `new MP.Map(scope.options);` Your MP.map doesn't know what element to use. Hard to say since i and google are completely unfamiliar with `MP.map`. What does it have to do with Leaflet? Perhaps you could share some code.

> failing to get instance of MP.Map in angular controller

Your controller code runs before your directive's link function. So when you do try to access the map instance via `$scope.map` in the controller, it's not available yet. There are multiple ways you can solve this.

1. Use `$watch` on `$scope.map` and wait for the instance:
   http://plnkr.co/edit/N9DwdHQUIzxhqax6mwMm?p=preview
2. `scope.$broadcast` an event after instanciating and catch it in your controller:
   http://plnkr.co/edit/QB8fXMM67FD4NgMS49j7?p=preview
3. Bind to a callback function in your controller:
   http://plnkr.co/edit/PFvJzSliDo8uLFk8HgOi?p=preview
4. Create a promise in a service and resolve it:
   http://plnkr.co/edit/DoJpGqtR7TWmKAeBZiYJ?p=preview

Comment: Sorry for not writing the code of 'MP. 'It's a custom  class. Please check the edit part of actual question. Thanks